# System.IO.File does not contain ReadAllBytes C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In C# I am creating simple facebook application for WP7 and I came across a problem.

I'm trying to do the part where you can upload a picture in the album or feed.

Code:

```
FacebookMediaObject facebookUploader = new FacebookMediaObject { FileName = "SplashScreenImage.jpg", ContentType = "image/jpg" };

var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~") + facebookUploader.FileName);
facebookUploader.SetValue(bytes);
```

Error:

- System.IO.File does not contain a definition for ReadAllBytes

Comment: +1 for posting this as a separate question with code included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Code:

```
string imageName = boxPostImage.Text;
StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
Uri jpegUri = new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative);
sri = Application.GetResourceStream(jpegUri);

try
{
    byte[] imageData = new byte[sri.Stream.Length];
    sri.Stream.Read(imageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(sri.Stream.Length));

    FacebookMediaObject fbUpload = new FacebookMediaObject
    {
         FileName = imageName,
         ContentType = "image/jpg"
    };
    fbUpload.SetValue(imageData);


    IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("access_token", _AccessToken);
    parameters.Add("source", fbUpload);

    //_fbClient.PostAsync("/"+MainPage._albumId+"/photos", parameters);
    _fbClient.PostAsync("/me/photos", parameters);


    MessageBox.Show("Image has been posted successfully..");
}
catch (Exception error)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, there's an error occured, please try again.");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You've got a couple of problems there. First off, Server.MapPath isn't going to give you the file location (since you're not in a web application). But once you do know the file path you're looking for (in IsolatedStorage), you can do something like this to read in the file as a byte array:

```
    public byte[] ReadFile(String fileName)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = appStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bytes = new byte[file.Length];

                var count = 1024;
                var read = file.Read(bytes, 0, count);
                var blocks = 1;
                while(read > 0)
                {
                    read = file.Read(bytes, blocks * count, count); 
                    blocks += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: I'd use a "using" block for `isolatedStorageFileStream` - and read in a loop rather than assuming a single call to `Read` will get everything.

Comment: Updated to use a using block for the stream - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ... Aaannnd updated again to read in a loop because I just realized that the length of the file is an Int64, and might exceed the ability of Read to read the whole file at once. Thanks for keeping me honest, Jon.

Comment: @E.Z. Hart: That's always going to read to the *start* of the array. You need to keep updating where you're reading to :) See http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

Comment: Thank you all for answers.. I will try with your example.

Comment: I get error: The name GetFileName does not exists in the current context. What is wrong?

Comment: and the current code will just keep overwriting the first 1024 bytes

Comment: Fixed yet again to increment the offset; thanks to Jon and other John for pointing that out. Also fixed the fileName parameter. And learned an important lesson about answering when you're half asleep.