# How to upload images to facebook which is selected by using photoChooserTask in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows Phone app in which I have to post a photo to facebook. And that particular photo is choosen by using PhotoChooserTask or CameraChooserTask.

Normally, I can post a particular photo successfully, but I am facing problem to post the selected photo. I saw some link like
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502174/system-io-file-does-not-contain-readallbytes-c-sharp)

So please if anyone know about the issue please help me out.
Thanx in advance.

**EDIT**

```
private void PostClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Client Parameters
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        //var parameters1 = new Dictionary<>();
        parameters["client_id"] = FBApi;
        parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        parameters["response_type"] = "token";
        parameters["display"] = "touch";
        parameters["ContentType"] = "image/png";
        //The scope is what give us the access to the users data, in this case
        //we just want to publish on his wall
        parameters["scope"] = "publish_stream";
        Browser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        Browser.Navigate(client.GetLoginUrl(parameters));
    }
private void BrowserNavitaged(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
        //Making sure that the url actually has the access token
        if (!client.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out oauthResult))
        {
            return;
        }
        //Checking that the user successfully accepted our app, otherwise just show the error
        if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            //Process result
            client.AccessToken = oauthResult.AccessToken;
            //Hide the browser
            Browser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            PostToWall();
        }
        else
        {
            //Process Error
            MessageBox.Show(oauthResult.ErrorDescription);
            Browser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
private void PostToWall()
    {
        string imageName = "ic_launcher.png";
        StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
        Uri jpegUri = new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative);
        sri = Application.GetResourceStream(jpegUri);
        try
        {
            byte[] imageData = new byte[sri.Stream.Length];
            sri.Stream.Read(imageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(sri.Stream.Length));
            FacebookMediaObject fbUpload = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                FileName = imageName,
                ContentType = "image/jpg"
            };
            fbUpload.SetValue(imageData);
            string name1 = eventname.Text;
            string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            string message1 = eventmessage.Text;
            string date1 = datepicker.ValueString;
            DateTime datevalue = DateTime.Parse(date1);
            string d = datevalue.ToString(format);
            string memoType = "Tribute";
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var parameters1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters["message"] = name1 + "\n" + d + "\n" + memoType + "\n" + message1;
            parameters["source"] = fbUpload;

            webservice();
            client.PostTaskAsync("me/photos", parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }

        //client.PostTaskAsync("me/photos", parameters1);
    }
```

On clicking on a button I am calling PostClicked class and it will directly go to facebook mainpage and it will ask for login information. Like this I am doing.
Please check it out

Comment: In this code, I am hardcoding an image name and I am updating it in the facebook photo. But i dont want that to be hardcoded, my requirement is to select an image from camera or phone library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I can share a photo to facebook successfully by using photochoosertask or cameratask.
I am sharing my experience so that if anyone face the same issue can use it.

```
private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        SaveImageToIsolatedStorage(image, tempJPEG);
        this.image.Source = image;
    }
public void SaveImageToIsolatedStorage(BitmapImage image, string fileName)
    {
        using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);
            var fileStream = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
            if (image != null)
            {
                var wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
                wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

With this you can able to save the selected image to IsolatedStorage.
And then at the time of posting the photo to facebook you have to select the image from IsolatedStorage.

```
private void PostClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Client Parameters
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["client_id"] = FBApi;
        parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        parameters["response_type"] = "token";
        parameters["display"] = "touch";
        //The scope is what give us the access to the users data, in this case
        //we just want to publish on his wall
        parameters["scope"] = "publish_stream";
        Browser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        Browser.Navigate(client.GetLoginUrl(parameters));
    }
private void BrowserNavitaged(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
        //Making sure that the url actually has the access token
        if (!client.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out oauthResult))
        {
            return;
        }
        //Checking that the user successfully accepted our app, otherwise just show the error
        if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            //Process result
            client.AccessToken = oauthResult.AccessToken;
            //Hide the browser
            Browser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            PostToWall();
        }
        else
        {
            //Process Error
            MessageBox.Show(oauthResult.ErrorDescription);
            Browser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
private void PostToWall()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data;
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(tempJPEG, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    data = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                    fileStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
            }
            //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            //BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            //// Set bitmap source to memory stream 
            //bi.SetSource(ms);
            //this.imageTribute.Source = bi;
            FacebookMediaObject fbUpload = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                FileName = tempJPEG,
                ContentType = "image/jpg"
            };
            fbUpload.SetValue(data);
            string name1 = eventname.Text;
            string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            string message1 = eventmessage.Text;
            string date1 = datepicker.ValueString;
            DateTime datevalue = DateTime.Parse(date1);
            string d = datevalue.ToString(format);
            string memoType = "Notice";
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var parameters1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters["message"] = name1;
            parameters["source"] = fbUpload;
            webservice();
            client.PostTaskAsync("me/photos", parameters);

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Thanx to all....

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by two methods :

1) by using mediasharetask in which it will show u all sharing account to which your phone is synced like facebook,gmail,linkdin,twitter,etc : it can be used like like this.

```
           ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
           shareMediaTask.FilePath = path;
           shareMediaTask.Show();
```

2) by using facebook sdk. you can get the package from nuget manager and then u can use it to share on facebook.

I hope this might help u.

Comment: But for this, i think user should have facebook installed in his phone. Otherwise it will not show.

Comment: yes for the first case user should have synced facebook in his phone but second one will ask for user authentication.

Comment: for the second method you can check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053346/upload-image-with-facebook-status-wp8

Comment: ok. But I want user to post to facebook account anyway whether his phone is synced or not. There should not be any problem regarding sync. Now I can post the message and any picture to facebook, but I want to post the image which I am selecting from photoChooser task

Comment: the second post which you gave is also correct, but in this I have to give the filename. And I will not be having the filename of that particular image to be posted. 
Only thing I can get is the path of image by using e.OriginalFileName.

Comment: have you tries the above link i gave in comment ... is it not what you want ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36253/discussion-between-imran-mozumder-and-sandeep-chauhan)